# Post PHP form data as XML to remote server

Tags: php, xml

I'm struggling to output and post form data as XML with PHP.

I have a series of form steps, at the end of which I drop various SESSION and POST data into a database - the easy part.

I then need to take some of this form data, and post it to a remote server as XML ( just the form data captured, so not multiple records).

Could anyone help with an example of how I can take some of the variables just posted into the DB, and send the as XML via POST? The variables are all still available etc following the DB insert.

Any sript examples achieving this much appreciated!

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml) should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

There's a script [here](http://davidwalsh.name/watch-post-save-php-post-data-xml) that converts your `$_POST` variable to an XML string.

Hope that helps